# Tr is not updating its class

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I want to make a row in a table selectable, however whenever I click the row, the console log shows that it did the right thing, but didn't change its class. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Part of the Code, that generates the select feature:

```
    var tableconn = document.getElementById("connectionsLane"+laneid);
        let row = tableconn.insertRow();
        row.id = "row"+insertData.id;
    row.onclick = function() {
        if (row.classList.contains("selected")) {
            console.log("unselected");
            row.classList.remove("selected");
        } else {
            console.log("selected")
            document.getElementById("row" + insertData.id).classList.add("selected");
        }
    }
```

`insertData.id` gets increased by 1 each time the whole thing is called, whilst `laneid` is dependent on which part of the website the user is currently refering to (is a int 1-255)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (preferable as [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) that shows the described behavior/problem.

Comment: provide your html part also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how you can select a table row and style it using a function. This function can be used for setting class name on rows in any table in a document.

```js
// for setting the class name on a row in a table
const onrowselect = e => {
  let table = e.target.closest('table');
  let trs = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  // remove all class=selected
  trs.forEach(tr => tr.classList.remove('selected'));
  // the current tr
  var tr = e.target.closest('tr');
  tr.classList.add('selected');
};

// define a table
var table01 = document.getElementById('table01');
// add and eventlistener to the table
table01.addEventListener('click', onrowselect);
```

```css
tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<table id="table01">
  <tr>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```